# Sagemaker batch transform job - Input data location

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I am using custom algorithm in AWS Sagemaker and used boto3 "create_training_job" API to train the model. The "S3Uri" location of the training data is passed to this API. Sagemaker in turn copies this data to the folder "/opt/ml/input/data/" inside the docker image and I have configured the training logic based on this location - /opt/ml/input/data/.

Now I need to generate inference using "create_transform_job" API. I am passing the "S3Uri" of the inference dataset, to this API. To which location inside the docker, will this inference dataset be copied over to? This is required for configuring the location in the code.

Answer (score 2):

When running SageMaker Batch Transform, the input is not persisted to disk on the compute instance. Instead, the data is streamed to your container via HTTP requests.

For more details on how the Batch Transform feature works, see: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/how-it-works-batch.html

For more details on how your container should serve requests when running Batch Transform jobs, see: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/your-algorithms-batch-code.html#your-algorithms-batch-code-how-containe-serves-requests